# Strange animation behavior

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I wanted to code this animation which has an equilateral triangle with points A, B, and C. The objective is for A to move towards B, B to move towards C, and C to move towards A. It's supposed to kinda spiral inward until it closes up. I wrote this quick canvas program to do that, thinking it would take only a few minutes, but for some reason, it doesn't maintain its shape as an equilateral triangle.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k3d8fbfg/

```
function Point(x, y) {
        this.ycoord=y;
        this.xcoord=x;
    }
    function init(){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    function getMagnitude(vx, vy) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx,2), Math.pow(vy,2));
    }
    var isPaused=false;
    function pause() {
        isPaused=(!isPaused);
    }
    var triangleSize=500;
    var point1=new Point(100, 100);
    var point2=new Point(point1.xcoord+triangleSize, point1.ycoord);
    var point3=new Point(point1.xcoord+(triangleSize/2), point1.ycoord+(triangleSize*.866025404));
    var count=0;
    function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

        triangleSize-=1;

        count++;
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        // if(count%3==0) 
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(point1.xcoord, point1.ycoord);
        ctx.lineTo(point2.xcoord, point2.ycoord);
        ctx.lineTo(point3.xcoord, point3.ycoord);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fill();

        if(!isPaused) {
            var point1p=new Point(0,0),point2p=new Point(0,0),point3p=new Point(0,0);

            var diffVector1=new Point(point2.xcoord-point1.xcoord,point2.ycoord-point1.ycoord);
            var r=getMagnitude(diffVector1.xcoord, diffVector1.ycoord);
            diffVector1.xcoord/=r; diffVector1.ycoord/=r;
            console.log(getMagnitude(diffVector1.xcoord, diffVector1.ycoord)+" "+r);


            var diffVector2=new Point(point3.xcoord-point2.xcoord,point3.ycoord-point2.ycoord);
            r=getMagnitude(diffVector2.xcoord, diffVector2.ycoord);
            diffVector2.xcoord/=r; diffVector2.ycoord/=r;
            console.log(getMagnitude(diffVector2.xcoord, diffVector2.ycoord)+" "+r);


            var diffVector3=new Point(point1.xcoord-point3.xcoord,point1.ycoord-point3.ycoord);
            r=getMagnitude(diffVector3.xcoord, diffVector3.ycoord);
            diffVector3.xcoord/=r; diffVector3.ycoord/=r;
            console.log(getMagnitude(diffVector3.xcoord, diffVector3.ycoord)+" "+r);

            point1p.xcoord=point1.xcoord+diffVector1.xcoord; point1p.ycoord=point1.ycoord+diffVector1.ycoord;
            point2p.xcoord=point2.xcoord+diffVector2.xcoord; point2p.ycoord=point2.ycoord+diffVector2.ycoord;
            point3p.xcoord=point3.xcoord+diffVector3.xcoord; point3p.ycoord=point3.ycoord+diffVector3.ycoord;

            point1=point1p; point2=point2p; point3=point3p;
        }   


        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    init();
```

Comment: Are `canvas.rotate();` && `canvas.scale();` not an option for you?